# J2ME BOSH client to ejabberd

Tags: java, java-me, xmpp, ejabberd

I am writing a J2ME client that must connect to an XMPP server through BOSH.  The server I am using is ejabberd.

I have two other applications that connect successfully via BOSH to the server.  The one is flash (xiff library) and the other is javascript (strophe).

My J2ME code manages to do everything up to the point where it must restart the stream using a body tag with a restart="true" attribute.

The ejabberd server fails to send back a stream start message at this time, but instead sends an internal-server-error.

The java code I have generates the same messages as the above two libraries.  From what I have seen in the ejabberd code the stream restart BOSH message and the stream features message is being sent separately in response to my stream restart request, while it is being sent at the same time fro the other two libraries.

Has any one seen this type of behavior?  What am I missing?

Below is a short log of the relevant part of the BOSH conversation.

```
[0][OUT] <body rid='1367396715' sid='fe67e7de6f99df688caa5b1977428f59a23bbb9b' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'><response xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'/></body>
[1][IN ] <body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'><success xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'/></body>
---SUCCESS!
Restarting stream
[1][OUT] <body rid='1367396716' sid='fe67e7de6f99df688caa5b1977428f59a23bbb9b' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' xml:lang='en' xmpp:restart='true' xmlns:xmpp='urn:xmpp:xbosh' to='test.wildeboom.com'/>
[0][IN ] <body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'/>
[1][IN ] <body type='terminate' condition='internal-server-error' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'/>
```

The ejabberd log file has the follwoing stream restart message.  Note that it does not have the stream features attached.  The stream features message is queued separately but fails to be sent.  For the other libraries this message has a stream features element attached.

```
D(<0.741.0>:ejabberd_http_bind:927) : ===[BIND]prepare_response OutPacket: 
[{xmlstreamstart,
"stream:stream",
[{"version",
  "1.0"},
 {"xml:lang",
  "en"},
 {"xmlns",
  "jabber:client"},
 {"xmlns:stream",
  "http://etherx.jabber.org/streams"},
 {"id",
  "1974251422"},
 {"from",
  "test.wildeboom.com"}]}]
```

Comment: i think that ur rid number has problem because u are using two libes connected to bosh.
i need more explain to help u.pur ur js code here that use strophe lib.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear.  Strophe is working perfectly.  The java code that I am using on J2ME is causing the problem.